# Projects that cannot be worked on independently

Tags: qgis

When I copy a project and make alterations to the copy, the original project is linked and adopts the same changes. How do I unlink?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: which operating system are you on? how exactly are you copying the project?

Comment: You seem to mistaking a GIS project for a CAD project.  In the CAD model, data lives in the project. In the GIS model, the data lives outside the project, and can feed multiple projects. You need to explicitly copy the data to a new dataset and point your project at that if you don't want shared edits.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are copying a qgz file. In QGIS, qgz files are just the project files which links to a database/shapefiles/gpkg, etc. You can have multiple qgz sourcing to a single database/gpkg. If you are directly copying a qgz file similar to this..

[image]

.. and the project properties's save path is set to relative.

[image]

then what you can do is just move the file to other directories outside your current folder and copy the package file relative to your copy of qgz file.
When you open the copy file, it should just be fine, if the package file is not copied relative to your qgz file it will prompt you to relink it.( I believe this is what you needed)

If it is set to absolute, you have to manually change all the layers sources to unlink it, but it is mandatory to resource it to other packages.

[image]